# Use activationStrategy: replace on a custom element - not the entire route

Tags: aurelia, selectize.js

I'm building a multi step form that asks one question per page.

Each question can be a different type, and sometimes the same question type will appear one after the other.

I'm also using selectize to enhance my multiple selects.

The problem I'm having is that when two multiple selects come after each other Aurelia won't reinitialise selectize, so the previously selected items will still be there in the new question.

Not only that, but going back and forward between questions eventually produces incomprehensible errors.

I've solved this by setting `activationStrategy: replace` on this route, and while this works it feels like there must be a better way to solve it?

I find it a little bit weird that such a "simple" setting completely changes the way my custom elements are run. With it it's like starting from scratch every time, but without it the only thing that gets called in my VM is the `questionChanged()` method (which I added as a way to detect when the bindable `question` object changes).

What's annoying though is that when `questionChanged()` is called the new question isn't actually attached to the DOM, so trying to reinit selectize in there fails (because the `<select>` element isn't in the DOM yet).

Should I just settle for using `activationStrategy: replace` even though it re-renders the entire screen and is probably much worse performance-wise (or?) or is there a better way to handle this?

I've tried using `determineActivationStrategy() {return 'replace'}` from within my `QuestionCustomElement` but that doesn't seem to work at all. Is it true that `activationStrategy` only works for entire routes? Otherwise it'd be ideal for me to just replace that part of the page, while keeping everything else as is.

Here's my custom element that fails to re-render when switching routes (unless `activationStrategy: replace` is used) (note, most of it is taken from: https://gist.github.com/monkeyhouse/fc5bd63ec852bad6b5e3):

```
import {inject, bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import 'selectize';

@inject(Element)
export class Selectize {
    @bindable name = null;
    @bindable placeholder = 'Select';

    @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) selected = [];
    @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) options = [];

    constructor (el) {
        this.el = el;
    }

    attached () {
        console.log('selectize attached'); // this is called the first time this element renders, but not again _if_ this component is on the next page/route too

        var el = jquery(this.el).find('select');

        this.selectize = el.selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            onChange: function() {
                el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', null));
            }
        });

        this.selectize[0].selectize.setValue(this.selected);
    }

    detached() {
        console.log('selectize detached'); // this is called if the next route does _not_ contain a selectize-element, but not if several routes in a row contain a selectize-element

        this.selectize[0].selectize.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the source code for the custom element, you need to implement code that will call the proper selectize APIs when the `options` property changes. You can do this using a `optionsChanged` callback.

Comment: @AshleyGrant thanks, that was an obvious miss on my part. I've now updated the code, but unless I use `activationStrategy: replace` I still get weird errors like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` and `Uncaught Error: Only null or Array instances can be bound to a multi-select.` when I go back and forward between questions. These types of errors are so annoying as well because they often point to `vendor-bundle.js` which obviously isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

The 'replace' activation strategy causes the VM and View to be replaced when navigating to this route, even if you are staying on the same route. You could try the 'invokeLifecycle' activation strategy and do write some code in the `activate` callback to update the values of your select elements based on the new route parameters.

As to why `determineActivationStrategy` doesn't work on a Custom Element, this is because Custom Elements aren't routed components, and so they don't have a activation strategy.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to use `replace` on just one part of the page? Cause that would be much better in my case.

Comment: Without some example code, it's going to be hard for me to provide recommendations for you. There are ways to have the router replacing stuff in multiple places on a page, but I'm not sure if that would make sense for you or not.

Comment: Hmm I guess I might be able to use a `router-view` where the one component I want `replace`:d is rendered, but it feels wrong. Is that what you meant?

Comment: This seems to be roughly the same problem as mine: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/79 and the suggestion is to use microTasks? Basically since `attached()` and `detached()` never run unless I use `activationStrategy: replace` I need some other way of knowing when the DOM has changed. Again, the ideal solution would be to use `activationStrategy: replace` on just the one custom element. I fail to understand why that's impossible

Comment: I've updated the question with my custom element's code. The problem is that attached is only called the first time it's rendered, so if the next route also contains a selectize element it won't be called again, and while the data in the component is updated, its UI is not and the answers from the previous question are still visible in the new question. I'd like to always destroy this element regardless of whether it's used several routes in a row.